# Geometry nodes: is there a way to separate parts of mesh that are only connected by one vertex?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, vertices, faces, random

[image: Image of merged "islands" in mesh]

[image: Image of nodes]

I used a random value to get portions of mesh from a grid and I am now trying create mesh islands that I can inset. There are parts of the mesh that are only connected by one vertex that I am trying to separate so that the inset node works better. Is this possible currently with geometry nodes? I tried used vertex neighbors and face neighbors nodes but I can't seem to separate the mesh correctly. Any reply is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The picture was a bit misleading. I essentially want the mesh separated in a way similar to the left portion of this picture. Currently it looks like the right mesh, so I am assuming I need to separate the mesh at that vertex[image: Updated Image]

Comment: If you enable "Individual" in the Inset node won't help?

Comment: The picture is a bit misleading sorry about that. The island may be larger than 2 blocks. I just want to seperate where there is a single vertex connection

Comment: Clicking individual will inset each face individually

Comment: I was thinking about your problem a little, but I've come to the conclusion that there are too many unknowns in your question. First with reference to your words "The island may be larger than 2 blocks."... then please provide better example of what may be the input and what is the desired output. Providing your blender file would also help. Also are you looking for this particular piece of knowledge or it doesn't matter what way we achieve the result?

Comment: There's something wrong with your inset group node. you should share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Blender.SE! Unfortunately, this result is actually due to the incorrect functioning of the [BB_Inset](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/bb-nodes-add-on) node. Please contact the author of this node group, because this is a paid addon.

Comment: I think I found a simple workaround - just split edges with only one face: https://i.imgur.com/A21J9Cy.png

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Since this is a paid add on I will contact the author as it seems like an issue inserting diagonal faces.